# Hibernate Search + Lucene AND Operator Query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I am currently going through Hibernate Search 4.1

I have one Table (file_data,fileName)
I want to create one query like 
file_data:XYZ and fileName:abc.pdf

How to perform this query?
Below I have try to make query for this..

```
Query luceQry3 = queryBuilder
                    .bool()
                    .must(
                            queryBuilder
                            .bool()
                                .must(
                                        queryBuilder.
                                        keyword().
                                        onField("file_data")
                                        .ignoreFieldBridge()
                                        .matching("HDFC")
                                        .createQuery()).createQuery())
                    .must(queryBuilder.
                            keyword().
                            onField("fileName")
                            .ignoreFieldBridge()
                            .matching("0_119.pdf")
                            .createQuery()).createQuery();
```

but this query and

```
Query luceneQry = queryBuilder.keyword().
                        onField("file_data").ignoreFieldBridge().
                        matching("HDFC").
                        createQuery();
```

returns same result.
I want to use AND operator so that I can minimize the query result.

------- My Entity Mapping  is given below-----

```
@Entity
@Table(name="file_upload")
@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl = org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.class)
public class FileUploadModel implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5376124674712529869L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Field(index=Index.YES,store=Store.NO)
    @DocumentId
    private Integer file_upload_id;

    @Column(name="file_name")
    @Field(index=Index.YES,store=Store.YES)
    private String fileName;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name="file_type")
    private String file_type;


    @Column(name="file_data")
    @Lob
    @Field(index=Index.YES,store=Store.NO,name="file_data")
    @FieldBridge(impl=com.test.documentsearch.core.BlobToString.class )
    private byte[] file_data;

    public Integer getFile_upload_id() {
        return file_upload_id;
    }

    public void setFile_upload_id(Integer file_upload_id) {
        this.file_upload_id = file_upload_id;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public String getFile_type() {
        return file_type;
    }


    public void setFile_type(String file_type) {
        this.file_type = file_type;
    }


    public byte[] getFile_data() {
        return file_data;
    }


    public void setFile_data(byte[] file_data) {
        this.file_data = file_data;
    }


    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

I have used FieldBridge...

```
public class BlobToString extends StringBridge {

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        try
        {
            byte[] byteData = ((String)object).getBytes();
            MagicMatch match = Magic.getMagicMatch((byte[])byteData);
            String mimeType = match.getMimeType();
            String extn = match.getExtension();

            if(mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg"))
            {

            }
            else if(mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf"))
            {
                COSDocument cd = null;
                ByteArrayInputStream bais =null;
                try
                {
                    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[])object);
                    PDFParser pdf = new PDFParser(bais);
                    pdf.parse();  
                    cd = pdf.getDocument();  
                    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();  
                    String text = stripper.getText(new PDDocument(cd));
                    cd.close();
                    bais.close();
                    return text;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    cd.close();
                    bais.close();
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else if(mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/rtf") || mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("text/rtf"))
            {
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[])object);
                RTFEditorKit kit = new RTFEditorKit();
                Document doc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
                kit.read(bais, doc, 0);
                bais.close();
                return doc.getText(0,doc.getLength());
            }
            else if(mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/msword"))
            {
                StringBuilder _result = new StringBuilder();
                try {

                    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) object);
                    WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(bais);  
                    String wordText = extractor.getText(); 
                    bais.close();
                    return wordText;

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else if(mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
            {
                StringBuilder _result = new StringBuilder();
                try {

                    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) object);
                    WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(bais);  
                    String wordText = extractor.getText(); 
                    bais.close();
                    return wordText;

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            System.out.println(mimeType);
            return null;
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return ex.getMessage();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you should disable analyzers for those fields, but to know that you should post the mapping of the entities too: which @Field options are being used on _file_data_ and _fileName_ ?

Comment: Your example query seems wrong as well. For example the initial nested queryBuilder.bool(). And then there is .createQuery()).createQuery(). Can you update your example first the actual query you re using?

Comment: @Sanne: Please took at my question again I have posted Entity mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make two queries

```
    Query query1=queryBuilder.keyword().
                onField("file_data").ignoreFieldBridge().
                matching("HDFC").
                createQuery();

    Query query2=queryBuilder.keyword().
                onField("fileName").ignoreFieldBridge().
                matching("abc.pdf").
                createQuery();
```

Add them in a list :

```
   listOfQuery.add(query1);
   listOfQuery.add(query2);
```

Then build a final query as

```
  Query finalLuceneQuery=new BooleanQuery();
  for (Query query : listOfQuery) {
                    finalLuceneQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
                }
                fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(finalLuceneQuery, <Youclass>.class);
```

This will work for you.

Comment: This is Working Thanks a lot...!!!

I have one more question..

I have created Query like..

`queryBuilder.keyword().
                onField("fileName").ignoreFieldBridge().
                matching("abc.pdf").
                createQuery();`
When I checked this query in luke.. then abc and pdf searched separately. I want to search whole word! How to do that?