# How can I use Hibernate search to search on several fields?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to find a way to search items in my database using Hibernate search.

What I have is an entity with several fields, and the fields I want to search on are indexed.
I would like to be able to search items with `fieldA==valueA && fieldB==valueB` (and maybe add more field to this search, if the user select more search criteria).

I am not even sure I should use Hibernate search for that or just construct a custom query.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've tried using a lucene query but only to search in one value in one field. I don't know if it's possible to do what I want with this. Also in others projects I managed to use custom queries but I'd like to find a more effective solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a hql query?

```
Query q = s.createQuery("from foo Foo as foo where foo.name=:name and foo.size=:size");
q.setProperties(fooBean); // fooBean has getName() and getSize()
List foos = q.list();
```

Source: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Edited:

Sees for a Lucene example to search on different fields
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/16009337/7141562

Anyway, i would stay with the JPA/Hibernate mode because it seems simpler and clearer solution.